# Unir fragmentos de un archivo fragmentado PHP (chunked file)

Tags: php, dropzone.js

He implementado una librería ([Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-chunksUploaded))  para poder subir archivos Grandes a mi servidor desde mi aplicación (los divide en trozos de 5 Mb) y funciona perfectamente.

Si quisiera descargar el archivo desde el servidor . como vuelo a unir los trozos con PHP?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**(No siempre el archivo subido es un .rar , puede ser cualquier tipo de archivo)**

os dejo el codigo utilizado por aqui.

```
index.php
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test upload by chunk</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/dropzone.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="components/dropzone.js">

  </script>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="control-group">
      <form id="cuadro" class="dropzone">

     </form>
  </div>

  <script>
    var Dropzone = new Dropzone("#cuadro", {
       url: "upload.php",
       maxFilesize : 600,
       chunking: true,
       chunkSize: 5120000,
       retryChunks: true,
       retryChunksLimit: 3,
       chunksUploaded: function(file, done) {
        done();
       }
  });

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

y aqui guardo cada fragmento

```
   upload.php
```

```html
<?php

function generateRandomString($length = 5) {
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

try {

  $nombre = generateRandomString();
  $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];  //seleccionamos el nombre temporal del archivo
  $ext = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']); // Buscamos la extension del archivo
  $ext =end($ext);
  $nombreCompleto =  $nombre .'.'.$ext; //creamo un nombre para almacenar en la carpeta del servidor
  $targetPath = "upload/";  //creamos la direccion donde se guardara el archivo
  $targetFile = $targetPath. $nombreCompleto;  //5
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6

} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo "
   <scrip>
console.log($e);
   </script>
   ";
}



}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el problema

```html
<?php
/* solo funcionara en Linux -- en servidor local de windows no ,
 para ello deberas buscar el equivalente al comando Cat para windows */

$target_path = 'upload/';  //direccion de los archivos
$complete = "completo.pptx"; // nombre del archivo completo - Deberia cambiar dinamicamente
$files = array_filter(glob("$target_path*"), 'is_file'); // busca todos los archivos de la carpeta y los une a un array llamado files
$catCmd = "cat " . implode(" ", $files) . " > $target_path" . $complete; // concatena para crear el comando 
print_r($catCmd); // imprime el comando en la pantalla
exec($catCmd); // ejecuta el comando de consola en (servidor)
?>
```